# Comparing time in database to current time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page to display a users profile.  The profile will show all the current bets on a game but only 45 mins AFTER the game has started.  I import sports games into the database and it is stored as a datetime field.  I need to compare the current time on the server to the start time and if it is 45 mins then display the data. If not not I do not want to display the data.  Here is what I have done.

```
<?php $today = date("Y-m-d"); ?>

<?php $newTime = strtotime('-45 minutes'); $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newTime); echo $time; ?>

<div class="row" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">

  <h4>Todays Bets</h4>
  <p>User Bets will display 45 minutes after game start time and display for the day.<?php $date = date('Y-m-d H:i', time()); echo $date; ?></p>



  <?php foreach ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM game_data INNER JOIN user_betting ON game_data.id=user_betting.game_id WHERE user_betting.handicapper_id=$uid AND DATE(date) = '$today' AND DATE(date) < DATE('$time') ORDER BY date ASC") as $bets) { ?>
```

As you can see I did echo the time as 45mins before the current date. So I'm getting a correct echo but when the game starts after that time I still am getting the response.  I should have no games.  What am I doing wrong here to make sure thisi only displays for the current date and 45mins after the game start time.

Here is [the page in action](http://wewatchcappers.com/viewuser.php?uid=2).

Comment: use the date functions with in the db engine itself. `date < NOW()-45 MINUTES`

Comment: A date cannot be the same as today then less than today at the same time (you are comparing the [`date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date), and not the time).

Answer (score 0):

You are pssing it in `DATE()` function which is going to reuturn only date `YYYY-MM-DD`, try below

```
 $sql = "
    SELECT * FROM game_data 
      INNER JOIN user_betting ON game_data.id=user_betting.game_id 
         WHERE user_betting.handicapper_id=$uid 
           AND DATE(date) = '$today' 
           AND date < '$time' ORDER BY date ASC";

 //Query now
 foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $bets) {
    ...
 }
```

`Date()` only going to check for date not time part of `DATETIME` filed.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this before and it was not working but I think at the same time i was not using my new $time string that I wrote.  I went ahead and tried this and it worked.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: just had a question on possibly tweaking this and was looking to see if this is possible.  is it possible to keep these displayed until 4AM the next day?  after 4AM then clear all bets that are being displayed?  Here is te code I currently am using that is working exactly as needed

  <?php foreach ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM game_data INNER JOIN user_betting ON game_data.id=user_betting.game_id WHERE user_betting.handicapper_id=$uid AND DATE(date) = '$today' ORDER BY date ASC") as $bets) { ?>